# Closing symbol inside QDomElement

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have been searching this problem without any result. Maybe one of you experts has an idea about this.
I'm constructing a .xml with various elements and attributes. The problem is that with using the QDomElement appendChild() method the closing of an element is not inside the first <> symbols. This is requested by the company rules.

What it is now:

```
<element att1="" att2="">
</element>
```

What i want:

```
<element att1="" att2="" />
```

What can i do to achieve this kind of layout?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you converting the `QDomDocument` to text? With the `toString()` method?

Comment: Is it really producing the empty `element` node on two lines, or did you just linebreak it in your sample for readability.  This is actually an important question.

Comment: This helped me to find the solution. A custom toString() method is used to construct the .xml and there I was able to edit the layout. I just haven't looked that far. Thanks!